# C# Web Browser: get contents of input texts when user submits form

Tags: c#, events, browser, submit

I have a Web Browser control on my C# application. I would like to get the value the user inputs in the text input of the form when he clicks the submit button (or changes the page).

I know I can use:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("inputA").InnerText
```

To get the value of the input tag.

My question is, how can I detect the submit event so that I can store this value into a string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still working this out as you posted this over a month ago, but if you are, here's one option:

If the document you're showing yours?
If you have the ability to change the html code slightly this can be done fairly simply:

First put this right above your class declaration:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
```

So that the browser can see your class.
You also need to set your class as the scripting object for the document. ie: (only needs to set once)

```
webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
```

For the html you'd do something like:

```
<input type=submit onClick="window.external.doSomething()">
```

And finally you'll need a public method in your class to call (obv):

```
public void doSomething()
{
   string whatever = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("inputA").InnerText;
}
```

I'm not that well versed with the webbrowser control, so if you are not making the web document yourself I'm afraid this won't work.

Good luck